# Dropdown selection menu, how to retrieve value from optional/other text box that appears

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showfield(name){
if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Other: <input type="text" name="other" />';
else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
}
</script>

<select name="travel_arriveVia" id="travel_arriveVia" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option selected="selected">Please select ...</option>
<option value="Plane">Plane</option>
<option value="Train">Train</option>
<option value="Own Vehicle">Own Vehicle</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

This is the code I'm using, and I'm not sure if DOM manipulation will retrieve the value? No matter what I try, "other" is the value that's inserted into the database when submitted, and not the optional text that's entered in the textbox that appears after selecting "other". Which is what needs to be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelector('input[name="other"]')` to get the value of the textbox with name `other`. Since, this element is not guaranteed to be there you can use the `if` condition to prevent errors. For the illustration of that `querySelector` I have used a button so that when you type in the value inside the textbox and click the `submit` button it will console log the entered value. You can use it based on your own situation.

```js
function showfield(name){
  if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Other: <input type="text" name="other" />';
  else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
}

function btnClick(){
 var otherElem = document.querySelector('input[name="other"]');
 if(otherElem){
   console.log(otherElem.value);
 }
}
```

```html
<select name="travel_arriveVia" id="travel_arriveVia" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option selected="selected">Please select ...</option>
<option value="Plane">Plane</option>
<option value="Train">Train</option>
<option value="Own Vehicle">Own Vehicle</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<div id="div1"></div>

<button onclick='btnClick()'>Submit</button>
```

Comment: I already have a submit button though in my own code? Will the one tied to the function still push the other values if selected? Thanks for the assistance by the way.

Comment: @Subnetwork what do you mean by `Will the one tied to the function still push the other values if selected?`?

Comment: So where would I put the document.query selector for "other" if I wanted to use the value from it to insert into the database - in place of lets say selecting train and it getting inserted into the database?

Comment: You cannot use the value for "other" unless there is something input in that textbox. Then, at this case you need an event like click or submit or anything else that will get the value from "other" and save to db. But you cannot do this like you do for just changing the options because if you do so then "other" will be blank each time for you.

Comment: After implementing this code, I'm still getting "other" pushed as a value to my Apache database even when text is entered and its not blank.

Comment: `I'm still getting "other" pushed as a value` ? I did not get this @Subnetwork

Comment: Could it be because yours is printing to the console? I'm trying to get mine to insert into a database

Comment: Alright sorry for the confusion, I should've been a bit more clear.

Comment: If you are getting the value of "other" then you should have saved that properly in db, so where is the problem?

Comment: When I select other, and enter my text in the dropdown. I then hit submit, but instead of inserting the text in the database, it inserts the "other" value still.

Comment: Are you sending the value `otherElem.value` to the db? You might have hardcoded that value replace that with `otherElem.value` and send. It should work at any cost

Comment: Just the select name which is travel_arriveVia is tied to the SQL, other is not anywhere else other than whats listed in the post.

Comment: @Subnetwork You can however accept the answer based on what you have asked for has been solved.